# Inheritance in python and constructor calls

Tags: python

The output is:

```
Class A
Class B
printout
```

Given code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class A"
    def printout(self):
        print "printout"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class B"

def main():
    myA = A()
    myB = B()
    myB.printout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was hoping for:

```
Class A
Class A
Class B
printout
```

as result... :/

Comment: dont put pre tags around code segments, it removes the syntax highlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you did not call the superclass's `__init__`.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this have to be explicitly added
        print "Class B"
```

In Python 3.x you could use `super().__init__()` instead of `A.__init__(self)`, but you're still explicitly invoking the superclass's `__init__`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly call the base class constructor like so:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

In python 3.0 the following is equivilent:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the ancestor constructor, use the [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super) call for this

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "Class B"
```